# What is the meaning of this notation $\mathbb C_2$ in Jacobson's Basic Algebra I?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, notation, quaternions

I was looking at Chapter 2 (Rings) in *Basic Algebra I* by Jacobson (1974).  (Section 2.1 is Definition and Elementary Properties, 2.2 is Types of Rings, 2.3 is Matrix Rings (the ring $M_n(R)$ of $n\times n$ matrices over the ring $R$), and 2.4 is Quaternions.)

On page 96, Jacobson defines quaternions:

> We consider the subset $\mathbb H$ of the ring $M_2(\mathbb C)$ of... matrices that have the form... $\pmatrix{a&b\\-\overline b&\overline a}$.  We claim that $\mathbb H$ is a subring of $\color{blue}{\mathbb C_2}$...$\mathbb H$ is a subgroup of the additive group of $M_2(\mathbb C)$.  We obtain the unit matrix by taking $a=1, b=0$....  $\mathbb H$ is closed under multiplication and so $\mathbb H$ is a subring of $M_2(\mathbb C)$.  ... Every non-zero element of $\mathbb H$ has an inverse in $\color{blue}{\mathbb C_2}$... and... it is contained in $\mathbb H$.  Hence $\mathbb H$ is a division ring.

My question is what is $\color{blue}{\mathbb C_2}$?  Is it a typographical error for $M_2(\mathbb C)$, or a synonym for $M_2(\mathbb C)$?  I don't see it defined in the text, but I see it twice on the page.  (I figure a two-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb C$ would be written $\mathbb C^2$ (superscript $2$).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I expect that this is a typo.  On page 98 of the second edition of the text (published 1985), it has "$M_2(\mathbb{C})$" where you first have "$\mathbb{C}_2$":

[image]

and again on page 99, where you have $\mathbb{C}_2$ again, it has "$M_2(\mathbb{C})$" again:

[image]

Comment: Thank you; it is reassuring to see that $\mathbb C_2$ was replaced with $M_2(\mathbb C)$ in a subsequent edition.  My old edition has in the exercises for that section "Show that the subring of $\mathbb C_2$ generated by $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb H$ is $\mathbb C_2$", and I wonder if $\mathbb C_2$ was also changed to $M_2(\mathbb C)$ there for the newer edition

Comment: @J.W.Tanner $\mathbb{C}_2$ was indeed also changed to $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ in that exercise. :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the book you mention, so I'm only answering based on the provided context.

Going by the definition (e.g., see [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations)), it looks like $\mathbb{C}_2$ is indeed a typo or an ad-hoc abbreviation for $M_2(\mathbb{C})$; if the book has a note on notational conventions at the beginning, that should tell you which one it is.

$M_n({R})$ is the ring of $n \times n$ matrices over the ring $R$. That makes $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ the ring of all $2 \times 2$ matrices over the ring of complex numbers.

Comment: Thank you; I did look for a list of symbols in the book but did not see one